CodeIgniter4 - 2 different environments needing 2 different configs
CodeIgniter4 - to develop, I run a localhost:8080. for production i git deploy to a live domain name. how do I make it so that everything works (baseURL etc...) when on localhost vs on live server? do i configure Config/app.php and put the baseURL as my domain name or localhost?
hopefully the question makes at least some sense. trying to wrap my head around .env files and the config files in codeigniter 4.
currently i have # app.baseURL = 'https://localhost:8080/' in my .env file commented out.
and public string $baseURL = 'https://MY DOMAIN HERE.com/'; in my Config/App.php file.
issue is when calling base_url('example'), on my local environment, link base become https://MY DOMAIN HERE.com/ and not localhost:8080
and vice versa.

Personally I don't use the env files I just git ignore the app/Config/App.php file and then you can use a per-deployment/environment App.php file.

@Antony how can i do this using git? because i use github as an intermediary and deploy onto my live website by pulling from the github repo. i dont know much about git aside from the basics. hopefully my question makes sense

Absolutely - what you do is add a .gitignore file and that should then ignore those files from being included in your Git pushes. Just make sure they are when you run git status if you see your config files there then you know they're not being ignored.

@Antony when i pull to deploy onto my live site it wont overwrite/delete my existing .env file correct?

If you exclude your .env file and it isn't in status it shouldn't but always worth backing up your live one just in case.

1)App.php (baseURL): Update the baseURL in the App.php file to reflect your live server URL.
2).env file: If you're using the .env file for environment-specific configuration, update the APP_BASE_URL variable in the .env file to match your live server URL. Additionally, ensure that other variables such as database credentials (DATABASE, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD, etc.) are correctly configured for your live environment.

how do i make it so that i have a local .env file and a different .env file for the live website? using git. since i pull from git to live server and .env file must be different for live server
